# Write a drop down menu in Backbone View

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

My data returns 3 objects in an array.  I am looping through the array to grab the value of the id property out of each object.

I want to build a select menu, with 3 `<option>` tags.  Each option would contain the value of the id from the object.  I am not sure why my select menu is not rendering.  Here is my code:

```
(function () {

  var DimensionsModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url: 'http://jsonstub.com/calltestdata'

  });


  var DimensionsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.js-container',

    initialize: function () {
        var that = this;
        this.listenTo(this.model,'change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch({
            beforeSend: setHeader
        });
    },

    render: function () {
        console.log('inside render');
        console.log(this.model);
        console.log( this.model.get('dimensions').length );  //returns length of 3
        console.log( this.model.get('dimensions')[0].id ); //returns the id I expect

        var menu = '<select>';
        for (var i = 0, dimensionsLength = this.model.get('dimensions').length; i < dimensionsLength; i++) {
            console.log('ID = ' + this.model.get('dimensions')[i].id);
            menu += '<options>' + this.model.get('dimensions')[i].id + '</options>';

        }

        menu += '</select>';
        $(menu).appendTo(this.$el);

        return this;
    }
  });

  var myModel = new DimensionsModel();
  var myView = new DimensionsView({model: myModel});

}());
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="js-container">
</div>
```

Edit:  Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/4UeRv/

Comment: I'd double check the element associated with the view as the rest of the code looks sound to me. What's the value of this.$el within the render method?

Comment: Do you have a `.js-container` in the DOM when you `new DimensionsView`? Is your `render` getting called?

Comment: @muistooshort I do have `.js-container` in the DOM already.  I have updated the question with an example of the HTML.  The scripts are loaded just before the closing `</body>` tag as well and in the order of jquery-1.11.0, underscore-1.6.0, and backbone-1.1.2.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `$(document).ready(...)` wrapper instead of your SIF? That's an easy thing to check.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, I tried that but still no luck.  I am thinking it's a syntax error that I am just not seeing.  I added a fiddle to the question.

Comment: Um, HTML doesn't have an `<options>` element, it has an `<option>` element though: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/xz89U/ I probably should have spotted that yesterday, sorry.

Comment: @muistooshort Thank you!  I know there's know <options> element lol though that's probably not obvious from my mistake.  Thanks again! Sorry for posting a question with such a simple fix.  I think I just was missing that because I was thinking my backbone implementation was the problem.  It's quite a lot too learn.

Comment: No worries. Some of the hardest bugs to see are the obvious ones that are staring you right in the face.

Answer (score 1):

Also you should use `Backbone.Collection` if your API returns objects in an array.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I am new to Backbone and am little confused on when to use a Model and when to use a Collection.  Do you know of any good references?  There's a lot of tutorials I've been going through but I guess it just hasn't clicked yet.  Thank you for the advice!

Comment: There is a pretty good free book about Backbone.js: http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/

Answer (score 0):

There's a small mistake in you code:

you are using:

```
$(menu).appendTo(this.$el);
```

you should use:

```
$('.js-container').html(menu);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but that did not help.  It appears that the <option> tags are not getting written between the <select> tags.  I added a fiddle to the question as well.

Comment: When i checked the fiddle link you posted here, it seams that option are getting rendered in between select tag.

Comment: muistooshort provided the answer in the comments of the question. :)